# Regex to get a specific parameter from a URL

Tags: javascript, regex

assume that we have a URL like this

http://localhost:8080/dev.html?organization=test&location=pr&lang=fr

I'd like to make a regex that takes the organization=test only so that I store it into a var.

So in case I have http://localhost:8080/dev.html?organization=test, I get the organization=test.

http://localhost:8080/dev.html?lang=fr&organization=test, I get organization=test.

No matter how the URL is formed or the order of  the parameters, I get

```
organization=<organization>
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your current RegEx, what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function, <s>assuming the parameter name does not</s> *even if the parameter does* contain any characters considered special within `RegExp`:

```js
function getParam(url, name, defaultValue) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = '?' + unescape(String(name));
  var un = a.search.slice(1);
  var esc = un.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, '\\$&');
  var re = new RegExp('^\\?&*(?:[^=]*=[^&]*&+)*?(' + esc + ')=([^&]*)');
  a.href = url;
  var query = a.search;
  return re.test(query) ? query.match(re).slice(1).map(decodeURIComponent) : [un, defaultValue];
}

var url = 'http://localhost:8080/dev.html?lang=fr&organization=test&crazy^ ()*key=cool';

console.log(getParam(url, 'organization'));
console.log(getParam(url, 'lang'));
console.log(getParam(url, 'crazy^ ()*key'));
console.log(getParam(url, escape('crazy^ ()*key')));
console.log(getParam(url, encodeURIComponent('crazy^ ()*key')));
console.log(getParam(url, 'foo', 'bar'));
```

`RegExp` escape method borrowed from [How to escape regular expression in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript/2593661#2593661)

#### Usage

```
getParam(url, name[, defaultValue])
```

- `url` - A well-formed URL
- `name` - The parameter name to search
- `defaultValue` (optional) - If not found, what value to default to. If not specified, `defaultValue` is `undefined`
- `return` - `[ unescape(name), found ? stringValue : defaultValue ]`

Comment: Looks like fun. It's a good thing the WHATWG is handling these problems for us nowadays ;) BTW, [the reference algorithm in the URL spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-urlencoded-parser) is using `split` and then a bunch of steps that include replacing any '+' by a space.

Comment: @Touffy ah, I forgot about `+` being treated differently... at this point I think I've done enough other things. If a user of this function is aware that `+` needs to be encoded / decoded, then I'll let them figure it out from this implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Why use RegEx *or split* ? Try this:

```
function getOrganization(){
    return new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('organization')
}
```

(requires a polyfill for the [URL API](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#api) in IE)

Comment: What do you mean by requires polyfill for the URL API in IE ?

Comment: @Ziko it means IE doesn't have this built-in, but it's possible to include a 3rd-party script so that IE can use this anyway.

Comment: I see. I really like this answer as it is the first time I hear about URLSearchParams but i will accept the above answer as it is more accurate and also has a regex that might help many others.

Comment: If compatibility isn't a concern, I really like this. Otherwise having to include a polyfill seems like overkill. EDITED: Although it's not very big.

Comment: @EliteTech the more edge-cases I'm finding, the bigger my solution is becoming... at least I consider it "accurate" now, though. Before, it wasn't even as robust as using `split('&')`, now it can handle various encoded URLs and names.

Answer (score 1):

Why use regex? Try this.

```
function getOrganization(){
    var params = location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
        if(params[i].split('=')[0] == 'organization') return params[i].split('=')[1];
    }
}
```